# Error when trying to access Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I have an anonymous function on Azure, successfully deployed (.netstandard 2.0), using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (1.0.13), but for some reason suddenly it stopped working and when I call it the response is:

```html
<ApiErrorModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Models">
<Arguments xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true"/>
<ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails i:nil="true"/>
<Id>91fab400-3447-4913-878f-715d9d4ab46b</Id>
<Message>
An error has occurred. For more information, please check the logs for error ID 91fab400-3447-4913-878f-715d9d4ab46b
</Message>
<RequestId>0fb00298-733d-4d88-9e73-c328d024e1bb</RequestId>
<StatusCode>InternalServerError</StatusCode>
</ApiErrorModel>
```

How to figure that out?

EDIT: When I start AF environment locally and run the function it works as expected, without any issues, although what i see in console is a message in red:

[image]

and searching for it, stumbled across this GitHub post:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2765

where I noticed this part:

> @m-demydiuk noticed that azure function works with this error in the console. So this red error doesn't break function on the local machine. But I am afraid it may cause any problems in other environments.

and it bothers me. Can it be the problem?

I use a lib with a version that do not match my target framework, but again locally works fine, and also it was working fine before on Azure

[image]

**My host version is "Version=2.0.11651.0"**

This is the entire function:

```html
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("HTML2IMG")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            string url = req.Query["url"];

            byte[] EncodedData = Convert.FromBase64String(url);
            string DecodedURL = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(EncodedData);

            string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            DecodedURL = DecodedURL ?? data?.name;
            var api = new HtmlToPdfOrImage.Api("9123314e-219c-342d-a763-0a3dsdf8ad21", "vmZ31vyg");

            var ApiResult = api.Convert(new Uri($"{DecodedURL}"), new HtmlToPdfOrImage.GenerateSettings() { OutputType = HtmlToPdfOrImage.OutputType.Image });

            string BlobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
            string ImageURL = await CreateBlob($"{BlobName}.png", (byte[])ApiResult.model, log);
            var Result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var oJSON = new { url = ImageURL, hash = BlobName };
            var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oJSON);

            Result.Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn);
            Result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            return Result;
        }

        private async static Task<string> CreateBlob(string name, byte[] data, TraceWriter log)
        {
            string accessKey = "xxx";
            string accountName = "xxx";
            string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + accessKey + ";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("images");

            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            BlobContainerPermissions permissions = await container.GetPermissionsAsync();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
            await container.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);

            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";

            using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
            }

            return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

***DOUBLE EDIT:
I created empty V2 .net core AF in VS and published it straight away -> i get the same error... I even updated the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Function to the latest 1.0.14 instead of 1.0.13 and still get the same error. Obviously something in Azure or Visual Studio (15.7.5) is broken?!?!***

Comment: Could you show the code of azure fuction?

Comment: No, but it works perfectly on localhost, so I don't think the problem is with the code-behind

Comment: bcoz its show internal serve error so we have to check which line gives error on live but not on local

Comment: I also want to see this information, but isn't it possible to get it somewhere from the Azure Portal, maybe some logs?

Comment: @nmrlqa4 The java_home tip is not the problem. Could you tell us your function host version, see it in your CLI output `Starting Host (...,Version=2.xxx,...)`.

Comment: I created empty function, published it and still get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

On Azure portal, go to Function app settings check your Runtime Version. It is probably `Runtime version: 1.0.11913.0 (~1)` on your side. This is the problem. Change `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `beta` in Application settings and your code should work on Azure.

**Explanation**

You create a v2 function as your local host version is 2.0.11651.0. So the function runtime should also be beta 2.x(latest is 2.0.11933.0) online.

When you published functions from VS before, you probably saw this prompt

[image]

You may have chosen `No` so that you got the error.

Note that if we publish through CI/CD like VSTS or Git, such notification is not available. So we need to make sure those configurations are set correctly.

**Suggestions**

As you can see your local host version is 2.0.11651, which is lower than 2.0.11933 on Azure. I do recommend you to update `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`(on VS menus, Tools->Extensions and Updates) to latest(15.0.40617.0) for VS to consume latest function runtime.

As for your code, I recommend you to create `images` container and set its public access level manually on portal since this process only requires executing once.

Then we can use [blob output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output).

1. Add `StorageConnection` to Application settings with storage connection string. If your `images` container is in the storage account used by function app (`AzureWebJobsStorge` in Application settings), ignore this step and delete `Connection` parameter below, because bindings use that storage account by default.
2. Add blob output bindings

   ```
   public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(...,TraceWriter log,
           [Blob("images", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "StorageConnection")] CloudBlobContainer container)
   ```
3. Change CreateBlob method

   ```
   private async static Task<string> CreateBlob(string name, byte[] data, TraceWriter log, CloudBlobContainer container)
   {
       CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
       blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";

       using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
       {
           await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
       }

       return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
   }
   ```

Comment: When deploying via CI (ie. through VSTS) you do not get the popup notification and this error can be annoying to find.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the useful info, I will do some tests and update my answer later.